# Outline & border doesnt work in Tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Im used create-next-app to create my app, .outline & .border doest work, but border-b- (border bottom) does work.[Picture of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3lhG.png)

```html
<div className="outline outline-black outline-2">
  <button className="text-xl" onClick={closePopup}>
            Close
          </button>
</div>
<div className="border border-gray-800">
  <button className="text-xl" onClick={closePopup}>
            Close
          </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to inspect the styles and see if something overrides it

Comment: I think something overrides it, i heard about taliwind preflight that disable a lot of default stylings, and inside of my css there a lot of elements with --tw-[property] set to 0 or none. how to disable it just for button? or for outlines and borders

Comment: here is the part that blocking all borders 

`*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #e5e7eb;
}`

Comment: im finded something like a solution from here: [link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2994)
but how to add it to globals css?

Comment: I don't think it's the part  that blocks, since class selector has higher priority than all selector. can you add a picture when you inspect the element style?